# Google login button without SDK

Tags: ios, swift, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0

I have Swift app and I would like to create Google login without the use of SDK.
For Facebook login, I use `ASWebAuthenticationSession`. Is this possible to use this for Google as well?
When I try to setup OAuth based on flow from Facebook OAuth, I got blank screen.

I create URI like this:

```
let callbackScheme = "com.company.myapp"
let redirectUrl = "\(callbackScheme):/oauth2Callback"

let PERMISSION_SCOPES = ["email", "profile"]

let tmp = GoogleLoginHelper.PERMISSION_SCOPES.map { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.\($0)"}
let scope = tmp.joined(separator: " ")
           
var url = URL(string: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token")!
url.appendQueryItem(name: "client_id", value: "<MY_CLIENT_ID>)
url.appendQueryItem(name: "redirect_uri", value: redirectUrl)
url.appendQueryItem(name: "response_type", value: "code")
url.appendQueryItem(name: "state", value: UUID().uuidString)
url.appendQueryItem(name: "scope", value: scope)
url.appendQueryItem(name: "access_type", value: "offline")
url.appendQueryItem(name: "prompt", value: "consent")
```

However, when I use this with `ASWebAuthenticationSession`, I got blank screen.

I have also tried to use `callbackScheme` based on **iOS URL scheme** from google cloud management but with the same result.

Once I obtain code from API, I send this code to my backend server, where access token is obtained and based on it, user email, that is later linked to my login flow.
The same logic works on my web and I want to manage users only from one place on my server backend.

I also dont know, If I should create client id for iOS app (or Android), or use my web assigned one.

The login flow I came up with is:

1. In app, use client_id same as for web login and init Google auth page with redirect set to my backend server
2. On backend server, verify that request is from my app based on `state` property from OAuth
3. Exchange goole OAuth code for google access token
4. Use access token to obtain user email (and possible other info)
5. Add email to my database (register user) if email is not found
6. Use email to login user
7. Generate my server token that is send back to app (app will later comunicate with my server with this token to )
8. On app side, verify hash that the request response originated on my server and the obtained token is valid
9. store token (google is no longer used once the user is logged in)

Comment: You do need to create a different client ID for iOS OAuth client. Web/Server ID can't be used for devices. Also, I noticed that you are initiating OAuth with URL `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token`. No, that is used for token refresh. You should use `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?...`. Please reference the iOS Auth doc https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/native-app#ios

Comment: @GangChen After I changed url, I got the Google login screen and the code. Now the problem is, when I pass the code to my backend server, driven by PHP, that I got `unauthorized_client` error

Comment: For security reasons, you cannot pass the code around. Only authorized `redirect URIs` are allowed. You should be using what is called `3-legged OAuth`. That means the client initiates the process but the backend server does everything. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server

Comment: @JohnHanley So I can use the above code (with correct auth URI from @GangChen) where I use MY_CLIENT_ID from web app and set redirect URI to my server backend (same as from my web app) and at the end, process the resulting page?

Comment: No, please read the documentation. The process is simple, but you must understand the details. Also, I recommend using a Google SDK for security reasons. Most developers do not understand Authentication and Authorization and that is why they are so easily hacked. That can be very expensive in the cloud.

Comment: @JohnHanley I dont want to use Google SDK if possible

Comment: If you will not read the one link I provided, how are you going to write secure code? Correctly securing authentication and authorization will require reading and studying dozens of documents.

Comment: I have read the link and still don't see the problem with my solution. I use web-based OAuth with my server URI as a redirect target, process OAuth login on my backend (obtain email, connect the user with account on my server) and return my own signed token back to app. The entire OAuth is to get the email of the logged user, so I can pair the google (or other OAuth-based account) with my server registration. I don't store any access tokens, I don't pass them anywhere. The entire flow is managed by Google, I just call API without SDK as described in HTTP/REST documentation.

Comment: Is your backend code using the Client Secret? Now that you have the token, what are you going to do with it? Update your question with details and not via comments.